# How to convert any video to .avi with wmv1 codec using ffmpeg/avconv?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, avi, libav

I have installed ffmpeg to convert a video. I am trying to convert a .mp4 to a .avi video with the codec wmv1. How to do this?

I am using the command avconv in a Kubuntu terminal. Last attempt I did this:

```
avconv new_video.avi wmv1 old_video.mp4
```

And I always got this message:

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'wmv1'
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Important note:** [`ffmpeg` is not `avconv`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/who-can-tell-me-the-difference-and-relation-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv) – there's a difference between those. Many simple commands will just work fine in either tool, but you should always [download a recent `ffmpeg` version](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) instead of doing an `apt-get install ffmpeg`, because you won't get the "real" ffmpeg.

---

Your command is quite off. Have you had a look at any examples or [the documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html)? We also have [a blog post on ffmpeg](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/24/ffmpeg-the-ultimate-video-and-audio-manipulation-tool/).

You first have to specify an input file with `-i <file>`, then the encoding parameters, and then the output file:

```
ffmpeg -i old_video.mp4 -c:v wmv1 new_video.avi
```

That's the most basic command to achieve what you want. The audio will be converted to MP3 here using the `libmp3lame` encoder. Choose a bitrate by setting `-b:v 500k` or whatever you need. Same for audio with `-b:a 128k` or similar.

Comment: You were right, I forgot the -i and that link was what I was looking for. Thank you a lot!